# Select all unique names based on most recent value in different field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access database with a table called SicknessLog. The fields are ID, StaffName, [Start/Return], DateStamp.

When a member of staff is off work for sickness then a record is added to the table and the value in the [Start/Return] field is 1. When they return to work a new record is added with the same details except the [Start/Return] field is 0.

I am trying to write a query that will return all distinct staff names where the most recent record for that person has a value of 1 (ie, all staff who are still off sick)

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: ofcoursee it is possible.. did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, all staff that has been sick where it does not exist an event after that where that staff is "nonsick":

```
select distinct x.staffname 
from sicknesslog x
where Start/Return = 1
  and not exists (
     select 1 
     from sicknesslog y
     where x.StaffName = y.StaffName
       and y.DateStamp > x.DateStamp
       and y.Start/Return = 0
  )
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the query, please try again

Answer (score 0):

```
 select staffname,MAX(datestamp)
    from sicknesslog 
    where [start/return]=1 
group by staffname
    order by max(datestamp) desc,staffname
```

This will retrieve latest records who is sick and off to work

Comment: This will just give you a list of all the times people have been sick. It doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried this but it says "Order by clause datestamp conflicts with distinct"

Comment: @Leroy i have edited the answer now.. try the query now..let me know for any difficulties

Comment: Distinct is redundant (and possibly invalid)

Comment: @Leroy if you want before specific date.. then add date also in where condition. or retrieve top 10 or 100 records

Comment: It's not working because the query does not address your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by to achieve this.

select staffname ,max(datestamp) from sicknesslog where start/return = 1 group by staffname

it will return all latest recored for all staff. If ID column is autogenerated PK then you can use it in max function.

Comment: This just shows the last time people were off sick. It doesn't show their current status.

Comment: Then remove where condition from query. But your question is only name with start value is 1 right.

Comment: That would not improve the situation.

Comment: What you want to get?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to only return staffnames where the most recent entry for that person has a value of 1 in the [start/return] field. If staff have previously had a record with a value of 1 but have since had another record with a value of 0 then they should not show in the query. Thanks

Comment: If you check in where condition start=1 then it will give only who are all in state 1 right..

Answer (score 0):

This should be close:

```
select s.StaffName, s.DateStamp, s.[Start/Return]
from SicknessLog s
left join (
    select StaffName, max(DateStamp) as MaxDate
    from SicknessLog
    group by StaffName
) sm on s.StaffName = sm.StaffName and s.DateStamp = sm.MaxDate and s.[Start/Return] = 1
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. I tried this and I am getting an error message saying "Join expression not supported".

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using Access 2007. I'm not sure if there is another way to write the query but Lennart's answer seems to be working now so I have used this. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I've updated my answer. Access does not support `INNER JOIN`, so need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead.